# [Error:connect ETIMEDOUT 50.31.225.155:2525]

Tags: node.js, express, icalendar, nodemailer, postmark

I am trying to do outlook calender event for that i used mailing service and i am using express frame work and mongoose queries in my project

Here is my code below:

```
 var _ = require('lodash');
var Outlook = require('./outlook.model');
var icalToolkit = require('ical-toolkit');
var postmark = require("postmark");

// Example request
    var client = new postmark.Client('xxxxxxxKeyxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

//Create a iCal object
var builder = icalToolkit.createIcsFileBuilder();
builder.method = 'REQUEST';
builder.events.push({

  //Event start time, Required: type Date() 
  start: new Date(),

  //Event end time, Required: type Date() 
  end: new Date(),
  });
//builder.method = meeting.method;
//Add the event data

var icsFileContent = builder.toString();
var smtpOptions = {
    "host": "smtp.postmarkapp.com",
    "secureConnection": true,
    "port": 2525,
    "auth": {
        user: '***********',
        pass: '************'
    }
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport(smtpOptions));

var mailOptions = {
    from: '*******',
    to: '*******',
    subject: 'Meeting to attend',
    html: "Anything here",

    text: "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",
    alternatives: [{
        contentType: 'text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST',
        content: icsFileContent.toString()
    }]
};

//send mail with defined transport object 
exports.send = function(req, res) {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
};
```

I am getting 200 success message but after getting an error message

```
{[Error:connect ETIMEDOUT 50.31.225.155:2525]
code:'ECONNECTION',
errno:'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall:'connect',
address:'50.31.225.155',
port:2525,
command:'CONN'
}
```

I dont understand this error message 
and even i couldnt get any calender event

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: which service are you using to send mail in create transport method?

Comment: Hey @Deep i am using Postmark SMTP service

Comment: it could be an issue that you are being able to connect with the mailing service, just check if you are able to connect using the given credentials.

Comment: yes i can connect to that service but still the error is coming

Comment: 50.31.225.155:2525 the port here, made me think that something is wrong with service